# JOIN in SELECT messing up my 'id' field - SQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This is my query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *  
                                FROM zoekwoning 
                                    JOIN users ON zoekwoning.user_id = users.id 
                                WHERE users.email='$session_email'");
```

Basically the query gives me the values of all added rows from the database the current logged in user added. If I test this query in PHPMYADMIN then it gives me the correct result, being first column the id and 2nd column the user_id.

Result from PHPMYADMIN

[image]

Then I put in a while loop

```
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo "<form action=# method=post>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td><input type="label" name="id" value"' . $record['id'] . '"></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Gives me this result, if I check the array:

```
print_r($record);
```

[image]

First 2 values should be first and second column from table 'zoekwoning'.
But it shows the value from the 2nd column 2 times.

Comment: Which id should your script be grabbing?  It's ambiguous.  Instead of `select *`, specifically name the fields you are wanting, such as `select zoekwoning.id, user.id`

Comment: And for good practice, `WHERE users.email='$session_email'` is a big no-no.  Look into parameterized queries.  I.e., `WHERE users.email=?'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While fetching the data with `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` the `id` from the first table is overwritten by the `id` of the second table. So you should not use `SELECT *` if multiple tables with same column names are involved. Use table prefixes and column aliases like:

```
SELECT zoekwoning.id as zoekwoning_id, ... , users.id as user_id ...
```

Then you can access the values with `$record['zoekwoning_id']` and `$record['user_id']`.